# Runtime Exception Mocking groovy.sql in Spock

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock, groovy-sql

I've scoured around StackOverflow and Google for a while trying to find the right configuration/syntax for being able to run this code in a Spock Specification:

```
Sql mockSql = Mock()
```

However when I run the unit test, I get a nasty exception thrown in my face by CGLIB:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method groovy.sql.Sql.<init>()V from class groovy.sql.Sql$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d0b7cd7f
at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.MockInstantiator.instantiate(MockInstantiator.java:33)
at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory$CglibMockFactory.createMock(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:92)
at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory.create(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:49)
at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.JavaMockFactory.create(JavaMockFactory.java:51)
at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.CompositeMockFactory.create(CompositeMockFactory.java:44)
at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMock(SpecInternals.java:47)
at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMockImpl(SpecInternals.java:282)
at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.MockImpl(SpecInternals.java:83)
```

I looked at this question/answer - [Mock static method with GroovyMock or similar in Spock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824315/mock-static-method-with-groovymock-in-spock) - hoping it might give me a good starting point, but the class being mocked in my case, groovy.Sql IS a groovy class, so I'm not sure it's the right place to start.

I've successfully tested Groovy.Sql in other unit tests using GroovyMock, but I was hoping maybe I just missed something that can make it so that I can have Spock magic and Groovy SQL all happy together.  My apologies if I just missed the answer somewhere - hopefully I'm not repeating someone else's inquiry.

Comment: Does this work? https://github.com/nickmcdowall/Groovy-Examples/blob/master/SpockExamples/src/test/groovy/interactions/InteractionsTest.groovy what version of Spock and groovy?

Comment: Spock is 0.7, Groovy is 2.2.2. Sql sql = Mock(Sql) I just tried, to no avail.  It seems like this may be classpath/compatibility troubles, since it seems like other people have no problem with this kind of mocking.

Comment: Spock `spock 0.7-groovy-2.0` yeah? Can you try it in a greenfield project?

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Correct on the dependency version.

Comment: Have you added `objenesis` to your test runtime class path?

Comment: @peter-niederwieser Looks like `objenesis` was the thing. If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it and vote it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When mocking classes (rather than interfaces) with Spock, putting objenesis-1.2 or higher on the test runtime class path is recommended (in addition to CGLIB) . Otherwise, Spock won't be able to avoid executing the constructor of the class to be mocked, which may have undesired side effects.