# Spock, PowerMockito and static fields

Tags: groovy, spock, rule, powermockito

I'm trying to write a spock test with static fields (as expected output) that I define in the `setupSpec()`. I also want to setup my mocks and the expected return values in this method.

So I started with something like this:

```
package spocktest

import org.junit.ClassRule
import org.junit.Rule
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockRule
import spock.lang.Shared

@PrepareForTest(StaticFoo)
class StaticInitTest extends spock.lang.Specification {
    @Rule PowerMockRule instanceRule = new PowerMockRule();

    @Shared static Foo FOO1

    def setupSpec() {
        FOO1 = Stub(Foo)

        PowerMockito.spy(StaticFoo)
        PowerMockito.doReturn(true).when(StaticFoo, "x")
    }

    def "test1"() {
        given:
        when:
        def x = StaticFoo.x()
        then:
        println FOO1
        x
    }

    class Foo {}

    class StaticFoo {
        static boolean x() { false }
    }
}
```

There are two problems with this:
`FOO1` is null and `x` is false (so PowerMockito did not intercept)

---

I then changed

```
@Rule PowerMockRule instanceRule = new PowerMockRule();
```

to

```
@ClassRule static PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
```

Now `FOO1` is the Stub defined in `setupSpec()`, but `x` is still false (again, PowerMockito did not work)

---

Still having the `@ClassRule`, I moved

```
PowerMockito.spy(StaticFoo)
PowerMockito.doReturn(true).when(StaticFoo, "x")
```

into the `when:`block, which also did not work. Again `x` was false.

---

I changed `@ClassRule` back to `@Rule` and PowerMockito finally worked when defining behaviour in the `when:` block

`x` is true, but `FOO1` is null

---

When I define both `@ClassRule` and `@Rule`, only the `@Rule` seems to be active (`FOO1` is null, `x` is true)

Apparently, I can either have one or the other working.

---

Now, I have two questions:

- How can I use both static fields and PowerMockito? What am I missing?
- Is it possible to setup the expected return values in a setupSpec() (or any other) method outside the actual test?

Versions used:

```
+- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
|  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
+- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5:test
+- org.spockframework:spock-core:jar:1.0-groovy-2.4:test
|  \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.4.4:test
+- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2.2:test
+- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
+- com.athaydes:spock-reports:jar:1.2.7:test
+- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.5.3:test
|  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.5.3:test
|     \- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.5.3:test
+- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.5.3:test
|  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.5.3:test
+- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:jar:1.5.1:test
|  +- org.powermock:powermock-classloading-base:jar:1.5.1:test
|  \- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.5.1:test
\- org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:jar:1.5.1:test
```

Comment: Why are you using PowerMock?  What does it give you over Spock's Mocks and Spies?

Comment: the ability to mock static methods in existing Java classes, see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15834010/1239103)

Comment: this may help: https://github.com/kriegaex/Spock_PowerMock/blob/master/src/test/groovy/de/scrum_master/spock_powermock/PersonTest.groovy