# How to test method that uses Utility calls and need to return its input?

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I have a Java method that looks something like this:

```
public Map<String <Set<Something>> mathod() {
  Map<String, Set<Something>> originalMap = createMap();
    
  return Utils.fixMap(originalMap);
}
```

I have a groovy/spock test and I need to test the method and I need to mock the Utils and make fixMap() return its input.

Originally, the Utils method was a service and it was mocked like this:

```
UtilService mock = Mock(UtilService) {
  fixMap(_ as Map) >> { Map input -> return input }
}
```

I can't figure out how to do it. Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you mock the Utility function you do not test anything, so the test makes no sence

Comment: I have a simplified version of the code here, it makes sense for my case, I just need answer for the specific question: how to get the input as output on a mocked static method call

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824315/mock-static-method-with-groovymock-or-similar-in-spock) helps

Comment: Doesn't explain how the static method returns its own input as response

Comment: You cannot mock static Java (or any non-Groovy) methods with Spock out of the box. So either refactor your code to no longer use static utility classes - you already noticed how difficult it is to test them - or you wrap them in non-static facade classes. The least attractive option is to add Mockito, Sarek or another mocking tool of your choice, which is capable of mocking static methods.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your code is in Groovy, which it apparently isn't, there is not way to do this with Spock's built-in mocking.

However, you could use [Mockito to do the static mocking](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods).

In general, I advise against doing anything of the sort, as it normally points to issues with the implementation. Consider refactoring your code, so that `Utils.fixMap` actually gets injected, which in turn can then be mocked easily.